# How can I dress up a bike as a unicorn?

Tags: customization

Or a horse, of course.  The bike has to be rideable, and needs to return to normal afterwards.

Most years my city has what they call a "carnivelo", a family ride in which bikes, riders, trailers, passengers etc are encouraged to be in fancy dress and ride a car-free route.  There are [photos online](http://bristolcyclefestival.com/2014/07/the-best-carnivelo-costumes/) and [videos of previous years on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53om1B5NwVc). Some years have more fancy dress than others.

This year [the theme is "enchanted forest"](https://www.facebook.com/events/274547933341829/) so I thought a unicorn with 2 riders (my daughter fits better on her bike seat than in the trailer) would be suitable. We would of course be in fancy dresss ourselves. A "horse" could also pull a carriage based on the frame of the trailer with a new cover.

While the event itself is traffic-free, we'd have to get there somehow, which would presumably involve riding in traffic.

Comment: A slight complication is that it's only a few weeks away and I don't have much time. We may or may not end up taking part

Comment: Maybe some sort of papier mache 'skirt' attached by wire to the fork and seat stays, and a 'head' that attaches to the bars and maybe anchors to the head tube?  Recipe for disaster if its raining or windy though

Comment: All time greatest question contender?

Comment: I bet that horn makes you real popular in a paceline.  ;-)

Comment: Maybe your the unicorn and you can make draping fabric that cover the bike, you of course would also have to make a guard system so that the fabric could not get into the wheels or moving parts

Comment: If you had more time, building two significantly off-center wheels would give you a "cantering" effect.  Downside is this takes either a heap of different spoke lengths, or access to a spoke threadding machine and blanks.

Comment: @Criggie I'm having thoughts about legs attached to the forks, with linkages to make them move, driven off a roller on top of the wheel. That might make an easier ride. My wheel spares, and most cheap wheels I could pick up second hand, are 26", but everything else I've got is 700C, so there would be a fair bit of tracking down parts as you say

Comment: @ChrisH did you dress it up as a unicorn (or unicentaur) after all? Do you have pictures to share?

Comment: @gschenk unfortunately not. I didn't have time to do it for that event, and we couldn't make the one last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment i wanted to provide this highly detailed artistic rendition of my idea. Make the whole bike the unicorn with you included. You could pull your princess or fairy daughter in an adorned trailer as well. The bike could be covered with a fabric or cardboard skirt with a guard so that it cant get into the wheels or moving parts. Legs could be drawn onto the side as well.

[image]

Comment: that could work, though not using one of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Unicorn-Latex-horse-Costume-Halloween/dp/B01IH6PE7M).  Perhaps attaching a mane and foam horn to a (cheap/old/spare) helmet work do the trick.  It might look a bit like a unicorn/centaur hybrid -- maybe I should explain centaurs to her and go for that (via Narnia rather than classical).  The back wheel already has a partial skirt guard because of the child seat.

Comment: @ChrisH a centaur is another good idea, may look more realistic in a way

Comment: @ChrisH You mean [this Centaur](https://www.campagnolo.com/US/en/Mechanical_Groupsets/centaur/road), right?

Answer (score 4):

A minimalist yet inventive design [by Korean designer Eungi Kim](http://www.knstrct.com/rides-blog/2011/01/18/white-unicorn-bicycle)  has caught my eye:

[image: Horsey - picture my be subjected to copyrights]

You could use white PVC plumbing pipes and heat bend them.
Accompany it with similarly minimalist fancy dress and you're good to go.

Comment: I like it, but good luck getting a 5 year old to dress up as a "minimalist" fairy!

Comment: What about preparing matching fairy wings and a magic wand (thinner PVC pipe) explaining "the lighter the gear the higher you fly, my luv"?

Comment: I hope that's very lightweight plastic as, otherwise, well, don't slip forward off the saddle.

Comment: I know there are different types of PVC, water, sewage, electrical. The latter is most lightweight, though I'm not sure if easily available in white (surely in ivory where I live).

Answer (score 3):

Fit exactly one of these devices:

[image]

Comment: \*groooan\* That's 'orrible.

Comment: @DavidRicherby sorry, could not resist.

Comment: You could also wear exactly one of [these hats](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-dec-28-2005-san-antonio-tx-usa-ncaa-football-jake-sykora-6-of-papillion-64567170.html). I'm sure it would be safe instead of a helmet: you wouldn't need to worry about corn cushion.